# Web Animations API. FLIP messes up the borders during animation

Tags: animation, transition

There are some weird border effects happening during the animation. The first page works just fine, but the other one is the reason I'm writing here.
[that's a 46-second youtube video of an issue](https://youtu.be/nRha5n7kUY4)
Does anyone know the possible reasons why this is happening?

I was using this guide to accomplish this https://css-tricks.com/animating-layouts-with-the-flip-technique/

Answer (score 0):

It stretches because you are scaling the element, which also scales the border. You can invert the scaling on the border by getting the delta in width/height, and applying it to the border-width. That border-width should animate with the same duration and easing as the overall element animation.

For example, if your element scales by a factor of 2 and the border-width is 1, you will need to animate the border-width from 1 / 2 (0.5) to 1 to invert the effects of warping.

Comment: may I try the 9slice method and scale just the central square? Kind of hard to understand how I can make that border-width transition when there's only this 1px border.

Comment: I actually tried applying keyframe animation with various params for border-width but it seems like nothing really changes.